# Equivalent condition for independence of discrete random variables (check my work)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, proof-verification

This is a the first exercise from Norris' book Markov Chains. It seems like it probably should be very simple but I'm not sure if I understand the basics correctly.

The exercise reads:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be discrete random variables, show that the following are equivalent:
(a) $X$ and $Y$ are independent
(b) the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$ is independent of $y$.

Here is what I think:
(a)$\implies$(b): Let $F_{X|Y}(x|y)$ be the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=y$. Then $F_{X|Y}(x|y)=P\{X\leq x|Y=y\}=\sum_{a\leq x}p_{X|Y}(a|y)=\sum_{a\leq x}\frac{p(a,y)}{p_Y(y)}$
By indepence we have $p(x,y)=p_X(x)p_Y(y)$ so the result $F_{X|Y}(x|y)=F_X(x)$ follows.

(b)$\implies$(a): Assuming $F_{X|Y}(x|y)=F_X(x)$ we have
$\sum_{a\leq x}\frac{p(a,y)}{p_Y(y)}=\sum_{a\leq x}p_X(a)$.
Since the sum is over $a$ we can multiply with $p_Y(y)$ on both sides to obtain
$\sum_{a\leq x}p(a,y)=\sum_{a\leq x}p_Y(y)p_X(a)$
Then, because $X$ is discrete there must be some $x'$ that is smaller than all other $x$. By computing first $F_X(x')$ we can show that $p(x',y)=p_X(x')p_Y(y)$. For the second smallest value, say $x^{(2)}$ we then have $p(x^{(2)},y)+p(x',y)=p_X(x^{(2)})P_Y(y)+p(x')p_Y(y)$. Continuing this process inductively it then follows that $p(x,y)=p_X(x)p_Y(y)$ for all $x$ and all $y$ so $X$ and $Y$ must be independent.

Edit: A better way to infer the equality of each term from the equality of the sums is to note that since $x$ is discrete there must be a unique $a'$ that is $\leq x$ but greater than all other $a$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{a\leq x}p(a,y)/p_Y(y)&=\sum_{a\leq x}p_X(a)\\
p(a',y)/p_Y(y)+\sum_{a\leq a'}p(a,y)/p_Y(y)&=p_X(a')+\sum_{a\leq a'}p_X(a)\\
p(a',y)/p_Y(y)+F_{X|Y}(a'|y)&=p_X(a')+F_X(a')\\
p(a',y)/p_Y(y)&=p_X(a')\\
p(a',y)&=p_X(a')p_Y(y)
\end{align}

Comment: I think you mixed up the dummy variables $a$ and $x$ starting from the first equation. For the second part, you just need to consider the successive difference of CDF will give you the pmf of a discrete random variable. You need to be careful that a discrete random variable does not means it is finite; it only means the support is countable. So you should say: If the minimum of the support exist, then the pmf and CDF at that point is the same and done. For all other points you consider the successive difference, as all the points in support are ordered.

Comment: Yes, I fixed the variables now. The more interesting part is the inferring the equality of the terms (i.e. indepence) from the equality of the CDF (the sums). I think the argument in my edit works. What do you think?

Comment: Yes the edit is like what I mentioned. Technically speaking your summation is summing all support points only; So when $X$ is bounded from below, there exist a minimum support point and the summation has a finite number of terms only, and thus you may need to specifically deal with that point like what you did before edition. If $X$ is unbounded from below, the argument above is sufficient.